# Hoare Logic Loop variant on user specified value

Tags: logic, verification, variant, hoare-logic

I have the following problem:
pre-condition is True

```
int n = askUser();
int i = 0;
while(i<n){
  ...
  i++;
}
```

The variant I am thinking of is: `n-i`.
However, I don't think there is anything that stops the user from supplying a negative value, and in that case the variant will be negative (which contradicts its definition).

Is it possible to specify the invariant as |n| - i, or does n>=0 has to be included as pre-condition?

Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Be sly and negate `n` if it's negative.

Comment: I am not sure I am allowed to change any of the source code. I need to verify the existing code is correct.